# Respecting redirects on Flask routes in test environment

Tags: python, flask, travis-ci, pytest, python-unittest

I have a Flask backend that I am setting up testing for. It is in the early stages, so currently there are only 4 tests set up, but each one hits a redirect endpoint that should then be redirected to a specific location (dependent on login, session, etc...). All 4 tests pass locally in a fresh `pipenv` environment set up using the same `Pipfile` as Travis. For some reason it is not behaving as expected on redirects within Travis. For reference, here is my test structure:

```
class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()
        self.app.testing = True

    def test_blind_home_redirect(self):
        result = self.app.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 302)

        result = self.app.get('/', follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 200)
```

The first assertion does not throw an error, but the second one checking that it followed the redirect returns a `status_code` of 404 instead of 200. A second test using the same logic for a different endpoint also passes the 302 check but fails the 200 with another 404. One checking that all "protected" endpoints redirect to login results in an unexpected object being returned:

```
    for endpoint in known_login_check:
        result = self.app.get('/{}'.format(endpoint))
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 302)

        # Make sure all are sent to the index
        result = self.app.get('/{}'.format(endpoint),
                              follow_redirects=True)
        sender = pathlib.Path(result.response.file.name)
        self.assertEqual(sender.name, 'index.html')
```

This one fails on the `sender = ...` with `AttributeError: 'ClosingIterator' object has no attribute 'file'`, but again passes locally.

These all appear to be failing ONLY on redirection. Is there something that should be set up to allow this to work in Travis that for some reason my local machine is handling? Again, this is the exact same `Pipfile` being used, and I have deleted my local env and remade it to make sure, but it still passes locally.